# Why does me.pushy.sdk.Pushy result in a NoClassDefFoundError in Eclipse Indigo?

Tags: android, push-notification

I am trying to implement  [Pushy Push notification gateway](https://pushy.me/) in my android app as for push notification, but I am getting NoClassdefFoundError. My mainactivity code is as follows:

```
import java.net.URL;

import me.pushy.sdk.Pushy;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Splash extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Pushy.listen(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    new registerForPushNotificationsAsync().execute();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_splash, menu);
    return true;
}



private class registerForPushNotificationsAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Exception>
{
    protected Exception doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        try
        {
            // Acquire a unique registration ID for this device
            String registrationId = Pushy.register(getApplicationContext());

            // Send the registration ID to your backend server and store it for later
            sendRegistrationIdToBackendServer(registrationId);
        }
        catch( Exception exc )
        {
            // Return exc to onPostExecute
            return exc;
        }

        // We're good
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Exception exc)
    {
        // Failed?
        if ( exc != null )
        {
            // Show error as toast message
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), exc.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        // Succeeded, do something to alert the user
    }

    // Example implementation
    void sendRegistrationIdToBackendServer(String registrationId) throws Exception
    {
        // The URL to the function in your backend API that stores registration IDs
        URL sendRegIdRequest = new URL("https://[ip]/sahiyogihaat/register.php?registration_id=" + registrationId);

        // Send the registration ID by executing the GET request
        sendRegIdRequest.openConnection();
    }
}

}
```

and I have added the jar as well...[image: Java Build path]

And my logcat is :

[image: Logcat]

Cant understand how to fix this... Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first screenshot it seems, that you integrated this library from an absolute path on your disk, so it will probably never be "DEX"ed by the Android tools and thus not be part of your final APK file. At runtime this leads to the behavior you described in screenshot 2.

**Solution**

You need to bundle `pushy-1.0.7.jar` into your Android application. Therefore, it should be referenced **relatively** from the `libs` folder starting at your project root. Hint: Don't use "Add external JAR" when you reference it. This might be the cause of the trouble here.

See also this article on [dealing with dependencies in Android projects](http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects):

> Projects have source folders, as well as Library Project and jar file dependencies. With no other setup needed than adding Library Projects as a dependency in project.properties, a project’s classpath is automatically populated with:
>
> - The content of the project’s libs/*.jar
> - The output of the Library Projects.
> - The Library Projects’ libs/*.jar
>
> ...

Another (more generic) overview is given in the article [Managing Projects Overview](https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html) found in the Android Developer documentation/guides.

From the official Documentation of [Pushy](https://pushy.me/docs/sdk):

> If you haven't migrated your project to Gradle yet, make sure to include the pushy-x.x.x.jar as a library in your project preferences (in Eclipse / IntelliJ / Android Studio). Make sure to export the library with the APK.

So check if the `pushy-1.0.7.jar` file is placed in the project's `libs` folder and referenced from there relatively in your classpath setup. With this it should work and the build-process should DEX-compile these classes for later runtime loading.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but still after doing what you said and refrencing the lib relatively... i am still getting the same error.. dont know why.

Comment: did you follow the steps in https://pushy.me/docs/sdk ? if so, do you use Gradle or Maven as a tool for the build process of your project? Which version of Eclipse is it you are using for this project?

Comment: The next part is "Make sure to export the library with the APK". Without that pushy won't be bundled in the resulting APK file and it will crash with a RuntimeException as observed/described above. Also: Try to conduct a clean build and remove all old installations from your Emulator or real physical device.

Comment: 1.Copy the SDK to your project folder... Done that
2.Import the SDK into your Android project.. I am not using gradle
3: Make sure to export the library with the APK... Checked the jar  in order and export in java build path in properties

My eclipse is : Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Indigo Service Release 2

Comment: Look, Eclipse.org states: "Indigo is a past version of Eclipse. Please visit our download page for the latest version of Eclipse." - Indigo has been released 2011 (!). Could you try the very same setup with Eclipse Mars from 2015? http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ - I'd bet this is due to incompatibilities between the Android SDK tools and the old version of Eclipse. This is your path to success I'd guess, as latest Eclipse versions have improved Android Support (when exporting/building) APK files.

Comment: Thank you for bearing with this issue all this time... I ll try to do as you said.. :)

Comment: thanks it did help... m using eclipse mars now, and its working fine :)